# javascript variable from text file

Tags: javascript, filereader

i use this code to read text from text file and to load it into a variable via input. Can I set a path to my "test.txt" file in the local directory with code instead of input?

```
     <body>
<input type="file" name="inputfile"
            id="inputfile"> 

<script>

var text
 document.getElementById('inputfile').addEventListener('change', function() { 

            var fr=new FileReader(); 
            fr.onload=function(){
                text = fr.result.split("\n")
            } 
            fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
        })


</script>

</body>
```

Comment: no you dont have access to the filesystem from the browser only to selected files in input selection imagine the security problems ...

Answer (score 0):

> Can I set a path to my "test.txt" file in the local directory with code instead of input?

By design, **no**. A webpage cannot access a user's file by path, not even with all permissions.

You might want to take a look at the [Filesystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem), though.

Comment: @nikinn Can you accept this answer if it solved your problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of getting information from a file using javascript. However, you need to be careful about the security of these files. You don't want to serve data that should be private.

You can do a request to read the input files that you are referring to. You just need to serve those files as well. There are multiple ways of doing it. Look into XMLHttpRequest, ajax request and axios.